# Computing ratio of records existing in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Could you please help me with the *unknownComputation* in the **SQLite** statement below?

```
select t1.attr, unknownComputation as ratio
from t1
group by t1.attr
order by ratio
```

*unknownComputation* should be `(count(t1.attr) for which there exists t2.url = t1.link) / count(t1.attr)`

Not all URLs from t1 are in t2 and I'd like to find these ratios and group them by *t1.attr*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you provided, perhaps this should do:

```
select t1.attr, count(t2.url) / count(t1.attr) as ratio
from t1
left join t2 on t2.url = t1.link
group by t1.attr
order by ratio
```

However, this considers that one t1 can have 0 or many t2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming t1 has a unique id called `id`, try:

```
select t1.attr, count(t2.url) / count(distinct t1.id) as ratio
from t1
left join t2 on t2.url = t1.link
group by t1.attr
order by 2
```